# PHP won't run a simple echo script but it works on interactive mode

Tags: php, linux

I have a simple index.php file that contains

```php
<?php
echo 'hi';
?>
```

when i try to run it with
`php index.php`
it outputs nothing, no error, no warning or notice, just nothing and then exit instantly. But when i try `php -a` and enter `echo 'hi';` it works, any idea why?

Comment: Try the full file path? If that doesn't work, check the file permissions. Are you on Linux?

Comment: @Spudly still not working

Comment: Are you on Linux? Double check the file permissions.

Comment: yea, still not working, tried to run it with sudo and chmod 777 index.php

Comment: Try `php -f index.php`

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: I'm not sure then. I upvoted the question so that maybe someone who might have other ideas will take a look. I can run this fine in my cli without -f, so it seems like maybe a config issue, but not sure what it might be if permissions are right and you're able to run `php -a`.

Comment: Nevermind, it is because of permission issue, i tried to run it on non-root folder (i was running it on a root folder) it's usually worked with sudo but this time not, thank you